# React useState - Unable to clear array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I've tried everything to clear that array "characterAliver" in react useState(). But nothing helped. I know that is async and it could takes time to update. But it never do

Allocate characterAlive to useState

```
export default function Gameboard(props) {
    const [charList, setCharList] = useState([])
    const [mapList, setMapList] = useState([])
    const [characterAlive, setCharacterAlive] = useState([])
    const [roundActive, setRoundActive] = useState(false)
```

That don't work for any reason. Nothing will add to characterAlive. I did almost the same in another code and it works properly.

```
   function handleCharFound(event) {
        console.log(characterAlive)
        if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
            const newCharacterAlive = [...characterAlive, event.target.src];
            setCharacterAlive(newCharacterAlive);
            console.log(newCharacterAlive)
        }
        handleEndRound()
        console.log(`Char:${charList.length}, Alive:${characterAlive.length}`)    
    }
```

That works properly. Nevertheless, I know that isn't correct in react

```
   function handleCharFound(event) {
        if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
            const newCharacterAlive = characterAlive
            newCharacterAlive.push(event.target.src)
            setCharacterAlive(newCharacterAlive);
          }
        handleEndRound()
        console.log(`Char:${charList.length}, Alive:${characterAlive.length}`)    
    }
```

!! And here is the real problem located. It's impossible to delete the array

```
    const resetCharacterAlive = () => {
        const newArray = []
        setCharacterAlive(newArray)
    }
```

Here is the full code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Character from './Character'
import EndScene from './EndScene'
import '../Styles/Gameboard.css'


export default function Gameboard(props) {
    const [charList, setCharList] = useState([])
    const [mapList, setMapList] = useState([])
    const [characterAlive, setCharacterAlive] = useState([])
    const [roundActive, setRoundActive] = useState(false)

 
    useEffect(() => {
        buildCharList()
        buildMapList()
        console.log('Reload useEffect()')
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.timer === 0 && roundActive) handleEndScene()
    }, [props.timer])

    function handleEndScene() {
        const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
        gameboard.style.backgroundImage = ('')
        ReactDOM.render( 
            <EndScene 
            handleButton={handleButton}
            />, gameboard)
    }

    const resetCharacterAlive = () => {
        const newArray = []
        setCharacterAlive(newArray)
    }

    function handleEndRound() {
        if (characterAlive.length === charList.length) {
          
          // Update text and score
          props.setText('You Found All')
          props.increaseScore()

          //Update round/ reset data
            setRoundActive(false)
            props.toggleTimer()

          // Display select buttons
          const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
          const buttonGroup = () => (
                <>
                    <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
                    <button onClick={handleEndScene} className='leaveGameBtn btn btn-danger position-absolute'>Leave Game</button>
                </>
          )
          ReactDOM.render(buttonGroup(), gameboard)
        }
      }
      

    function buildMapList() {
        function importAll(r) {
            return r.keys().map(r);
        }
        const images = importAll(require.context('../Assets/', true, /\.jpg/)) 
        setMapList(images);
    }

    function buildCharList() {
        function importAll(r) {
            return r.keys().map(r);
        }
        const images = importAll(require.context('../Assets/', true, /\.png/))
        setCharList(images);
    }

    function handleSetupGameboard() {
        const map = mapList.slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)[0]
        const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
        gameboard.style.backgroundImage = `url(${map})`


        const gameboardRect = gameboard.getBoundingClientRect()
        const charWidth = 70
        const charHeight = 70
        const maxX = gameboardRect.width - charWidth 
        const maxY = gameboardRect.height - charHeight

        const newCharList = charList.slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        const charElements = newCharList.map((char, index) => {
            const xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX  + 1))   
            const yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY  + 1))
            return [
                <Character
                setText={props.setText}
                src={char}
                  style={{
                    left: `${xPos}px`,
                    top: `${yPos - (index * charHeight)}px`,
                  }}
                  key = {index}
                  onClick={handleCharFound}
                ></Character>
            ];
        })

        ReactDOM.render(charElements, gameboard)

        props.setText('Find Waldo, Lady Waldo and Wizard')
    }

    function handleCharFound(event) {
        if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
            const newCharacterAlive = characterAlive
            newCharacterAlive.push(event.target.src)
            setCharacterAlive(newCharacterAlive);
        }
        // if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
        //     const newCharacterAlive = [...characterAlive, event.target.src];
        //     setCharacterAlive(newCharacterAlive);
        //     console.log(newCharacterAlive)
        // }
        handleEndRound()
        console.log(`Char:${charList.length}, Alive:${characterAlive.length}`)    
    }

    function handleButton() {
        resetCharacterAlive()
        setRoundActive(true)
        handleSetupGameboard()
        props.toggleTimer()
    }

        return (
        <div  className='gameBoardDiv'>
            <div id='gameboard'>
                <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
           </div>
        </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling resetCharacterAlive?

Comment: I'm sorry. There is a "New Game" button after each round:                                 ` `function handleButton() {
        resetCharacterAlive()
        setRoundActive(true)
        handleSetupGameboard()
        props.toggleTimer()
    }` @NaveenChandraTiwari

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A (less rework)**

It seems like you're encountering an issue related to state updates not taking effect immediately in React. You could try using `flushSync`. It lets you force React to flush any updates inside the provided callback synchronously. This ensures that the DOM is updated immediately. Be careful with it though, since it has its own caveats and pitfalls and I normally do not recommend it unless you know your way around react and how to orchestrate DOM updates.

Some links for you to learn more about it:

- https://codingshower.com/react-flushsync/
- https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/flushSync

**Solution B (More rework and actually recommended by me)**

In your `handleCharFound` function, you're directly modifying the state by using push method on characterAlive and then calling `setCharacterAlive`. This is not recommended in React. You should not mutate state directly, instead use setCharacterAlive with a new array or an updated copy of the current state.

Another important note, direct manipulation of the DOM (like using `getElementById`, style, `ReactDOM.render` etc.) is an anti-pattern in React and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. React has its own way of dealing with the DOM, and when you interact with it directly, you can end up with inconsistencies in your app.

Like you are using react in some parts but then manipulating the DOM directly which now is causing inconsistencies in your virtual DOM comparison with the real DOM. When you call `ReactDOM.render()` or manipulate styles with direct DOM methods, you're bypassing React's diffing algorithm and potentially causing unnecessary re-renders and other performance issues.

Here's an example of how you might refactor your code to be more "React-like". This version gets rid of all the direct DOM manipulations and uses React's state and rendering system to accomplish the same things.

P.S. I am just doing a basic rewrite to show you an example and the implementation will probably need more work according to your game's requirement and plot. But, I hope this helps?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Character from './Character'
import EndScene from './EndScene'
import '../Styles/Gameboard.css'

export default function Gameboard(props) {
    const [charList, setCharList] = useState([])
    const [mapList, setMapList] = useState([])
    const [characterAlive, setCharacterAlive] = useState([])
    const [roundActive, setRoundActive] = useState(false)
    const [backgroundImage, setBackgroundImage] = useState('')
    const [charElements, setCharElements] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        buildCharList()
        buildMapList()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.timer === 0 && roundActive) handleEndScene()
    }, [props.timer, roundActive])

    function handleEndScene() {
        setBackgroundImage('')
        setCharElements(
            <EndScene handleButton={handleButton}/>
        )
    }

    const resetCharacterAlive = () => {
        setCharacterAlive([])
    }

    function handleEndRound() {
        if (characterAlive.length === charList.length) {
            props.setText('You Found All')
            props.increaseScore()
            setRoundActive(false)
            props.toggleTimer()
            setCharElements(
                <>
                    <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
                    <button onClick={handleEndScene} className='leaveGameBtn btn btn-danger position-absolute'>Leave Game</button>
                </>
            )
        }
    }

    function buildMapList() {
        function importAll(r) {
            return r.keys().map(r);
        }
        const images = importAll(require.context('../Assets/', true, /\.jpg/)) 
        setMapList(images);
    }

    function buildCharList() {
        function importAll(r) {
            return r.keys().map(r);
        }
        const images = importAll(require.context('../Assets/', true, /\.png/))
        setCharList(images);
    }

    function handleSetupGameboard() {
        const map = mapList[Math.floor(Math.random() * mapList.length)]
        setBackgroundImage(`url(${map})`)

        const newCharList = [...charList].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        const charElements = newCharList.map((char, index) => (
            <Character
                setText={props.setText}
                src={char}
                style={{
                    left: `${Math.random() * 100}vw`,
                    top: `${Math.random() * 100}vh`,
                }}
                key={index}
                onClick={handleCharFound}
            />
        ))
        setCharElements(charElements)
        props.setText('Find Waldo, Lady Waldo and Wizard')
    }

    function handleCharFound(event) {
        if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
            setCharacterAlive(prevCharacterAlive => [...prevCharacterAlive, event.target.src])
        }
        handleEndRound()
        console.log(`Char:${charList.length}, Alive:${characterAlive.length}`)    
}

function handleButton() {
    resetCharacterAlive()
    setRoundActive(true)
    handleSetupGameboard()
    props.toggleTimer()
}

return (
    <div className='gameBoardDiv' style={{backgroundImage}}>
        <div id='gameboard'>
            {roundActive ? charElements : 
                <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
            }
       </div>
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The main problem is that this isn't work at all `   if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
            setCharacterAlive(prevCharacterAlive => [...prevCharacterAlive, event.target.src])
        }` here nothing will changes. CharacterAlive is alway 0. When I use the other function I showed, it's changing but I can reset it  @Ahnaf Prio

Comment: Now I found the solution. I have to update data inside useEffect